# Check if the content of a cell in one table exists in Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 SQL Tables:

---

attributesKey

id-------------name

C--------------Crunchy

S--------------Soft

R--------------Round

L--------------Long

---

produce

item---------attributes

Apple--------C,R

Orange------S,R

Bananna----L,S

Carrot-------L,C

---

This is a simplification of the issue I'm having; But, I think it should highlight the trouble.

Users enter attributes they are looking for (ie. Crunchy) and I should show produce who have the Key value "C" (ie. "Apple, Carrot").
~Pseudo Code for the SELECT statement ~
SELECT * FROM produce AS p WHERE (attributesKey.name = "Crunchy") AND (p.attributes LIKE attributesKey.id)

I hope that makes sense. I've been looking at it so long, its just become a set of random shapes on the screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) like:

```
SELECT * FROM produce AS p WHERE FIND_IN_SET('C', attributes)
```

you can also use logical operators like `AND` or `OR`.

But a better solution would be to create a third able which represents the connection between the two. (The easiest way if you have numeric keys if your tables)

```
produce_attributes (produce_id, attributes_id)
```

and...

```
SELECT * 
FROM produce AS p
    LEFT JOIN produce_attributes AS pa ON pa.produce_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN attributesKey AS ak ON ak.id = pa.attributes_id
WHERE ak.name = 'Crunchy'
```

**Edit:**

Your `attributesKey` is called a **dictinary table** because it only resolves codes to values. And you have a many-to-many relationship between attributesKey and produce. Many-to-many relationships are represented by a connecting table in relational database management (or at least this is the most common representation of it).

So most of all I recommend you numeric keys and a third table.

Comment: Thanks for this,
The issue with FIND_IN_SET solution, is that I dont have the "C" I have the description "Crunchy", other wise using LIKE "%C%" would work fine.
not really sure how the third table would work. there is no direct correlation between the two tables.  the attributes column only contains descriptions. so one apple may be round and crunchy (R,C) and another could be Soft and round (S,R), while a third has nothing set. I Need to find the ID in the AtributesKey table before I can search for the Id in the Attributes column of the Produce table

Comment: @Hitcher'sThumb Yep, you have to resolve the `Crunchy -> C` operation in a revious step. But if this should be solved in the frontend. For example '<option name="C">Crunchy</option>' - it's not recommended to send strings when they represent records. It is more elegant to send the ID of the record. That's why I recommended numeric keys. You can have a table with '(1, Cruchy); (2, Soft) ...' and use a third table to connect the two original ones. Also read the edit please.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query -

```
SELECT * FROM produce p WHERE p.attributes LIKE '%(SELECT a.id from attributesKey a where a.name="Crunchy")%';
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've given it a try, and while both queries work independently, combining the two causes it returning nothing.

Comment: instead of `LIKE '%(...)%'` you should use `LIKE CONCAT('%', (...), '%')`